# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column does not exist

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm creating a one-to-many relationship between *User* and *Post*.

In one of the app routes, I'm trying to retrieve all posts with `curl 127.0.0.1:5000/api/posts/fetch`

The app route for this (in `routes.py`) is like:

```
@app.route('/api/posts/fetch', methods=['GET'])
def fetch_posts():
    posts = Post.query.all()
    all_posts = []
    for post in posts:
        new_post = {
            "id": post.id,
            "title": post.title,
            "text": post.text,
            "user_id": post.user_id,
            "pub_date": post.pub_date
        }
        all_posts.append(new_post)
    return json.dumps(all_posts), 200
```

This is throwing the below error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column post.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...post.title AS post_title, post.text AS post_text, post.user_...
                                                             ^

[SQL: SELECT post.id AS post_id, post.title AS post_title, post.text AS post_text, post.user_id AS post_user_id, post.pub_date AS post_pub_date
FROM post]
```

The `models.py` looks like:

```
from app import db
from datetime import datetime


class User(db.Model):
    id            = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name          = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email         = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    posts         = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)


class Post(db.Model):
    id           = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title        = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    text         = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id      = db.Column(db.String(64), db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    pub_date     = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % self.title
```

How can I retrieve the `user_id` column (which is a foreign key in `post` table) in the app route?

**UPDATE 1**: Changed `user_id` in class `Post` as per the comment by @Yogaraj but still getting the same error.

**UPDATE 2**: Below are the details for table post:

```
testdb=# \d post
                                       Table "public.post"
  Column  |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |             Default
----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 id       | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('post_id_seq'::regclass)
 title    | character varying(100)      |           | not null |
 text     | text                        |           | not null |
 username | character varying(64)       |           | not null |
 pub_date | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "post_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "post_username_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES "user"(name)

testdb=#
```

Comment: The model is wrong. `User` model has `id` as `Integer` and `Post` model has `user_id` as `str` when referencing it with `ForeignKey`. I think the table itself wouldn't be created because of this inconsistency. Did you check the postgres manually?

Comment: @Yogaraj thank you for pointing it out. The change in `class Post` is now: `user_id      = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)`. But I'm still getting the same error. As of now, there's no data in `posts` table and it should return `[]`

Comment: I'm not sure how the table migration is handled in sqlalchemy. Once the model is changed, it has to reflected in postgres. Can you check whether the column is created as expected after the change in postgres?

Comment: I've checked the table details and have added the information.

Comment: In the table, there is a column named `username` instead of `user_id` (which is defined in the model) because of which the query fails. Changing it would solve the problem. Is the table created via sqlalchemy?

Comment: Thank you so much @Yogaraj, my code is working